# If number in for loop less than 97, then add 26

Tags: python

I am trying to make a caesar cipher.  I currently have the current code:

```
import string

def code_to_encrypt():
    print("This program will encode your messages using a Caesar Cipher")
    print("")

    key = -3
    message = input("Enter the message: ")
    
    for letter in message:
        if ord(letter) > 96:
            print(chr(ord(letter) + key))
    
code_to_encrypt()
```

How can I make it so that the letters change by the amount of the key?  If the number is 96 for example, it should change to 122.

Comment: What is not working correctly right now?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a separate function to perform the shift

```py
def shift(letter, num):
    return chr(((ord(letter.upper()) - 65 + num) % 26) + 65)
```

e.g. `letter = shift('a', 3)`

You also need to have a shift of positive 3 not negative 3 (use negative for decryption)

```py
def caesar_encrypt(text):
    result = ''
    for letter in text:
        result += shift(letter, 3)
    return result

def caesar_decrypt(text):
    result = ''
    for letter in text:
        result += shift(letter, -3)
    return result
```

Output

```py
caesar_encrypt("plaintext")
'SODLQWHAW'
caesar_decrypt("SODLQWHAW")
'PLAINTEXT'
```

Comment: I'm getting a bit confused, could you please put it back into the example